# How to validate whether the entered aadhar number is valid or not using verhoeff algorithm?

Tags: javascript, c#

The below mentioned javascript code is for validating whether the entered aadhar number is valid or not.What i wanted to do is when user enter the aadhar number,it should validate whether the entered number is valid or not.I used a javascript for validation but its not working.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var d = [
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5],
        [2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6],
        [3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7],
        [4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1],
        [6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2],
        [7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3],
        [8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4],
        [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
    ];

     $('#UserForm').formValidation({
                        message: 'This value is not valid',
                        feedbackIcons: {
                            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                        },
                        fields: {aadhaar_no: {
                                validators: {
                                    digits: {
                                        message: 'Please use numeric characters only.'
                                    },
                                    stringLength: {
                                        min: 12,
                                        max: 12,
                                        message: 'The aadhaar number must be 12 characters long'
                                    }, identical: {
                                        field: 'c_aadhaar_number',
                                        message: 'The aadhaar number and its confirm field are not the same'
                                    }, callback: {
                                        message: 'The input string is not a valid Aadhaar number.',
                                        callback: function (value, validator, $field) {
                                            return validate(value);


                      }
```

Comment: The end of your code seems to be missing. Why the "c#" tag?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: the question is about the aadhar number validation. when user enter the aadhar number,it should display that entered number is valid or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that i just tried it to validate aadhar number by using javascript but finally i got a failure result.Then i tried it using a class in which i got a success to do it.So,In webform,i am using one textbox,one label and one button.

Default.aspx(Source code):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
   <%-- <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jquery.js"></script>

 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var d = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5],
    [2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6],
    [3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7],
    [4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    [5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    [6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2],
    [7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3],
    [8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4],
    [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
];

// permutation table p
var p = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 3, 0, 9, 4],
    [5, 8, 0, 3, 7, 9, 6, 1, 4, 2],
    [8, 9, 1, 6, 0, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7],
    [9, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 8, 7, 0],
    [4, 2, 8, 6, 5, 7, 3, 9, 0, 1],
    [2, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0, 6, 4, 1, 5],
    [7, 0, 4, 6, 9, 1, 3, 2, 5, 8]
];

// inverse table inv
var inv = [0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

// converts string or number to an array and inverts it
function invArray(array) {

    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(array) === "[object Number]") {
        array = String(array);
    }

    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(array) === "[object String]") {
        array = array.split("").map(Number);
    }

    return array.reverse();

}

// generates checksum
function generate(array) {

    var c = 0;
    var invertedArray = invArray(array);

    for (var i = 0; i < invertedArray.length; i++) {
        c = d[c][p[((i + 1) % 8)][invertedArray[i]]];
    }

    return inv[c];
}

// validates checksum
function validate(array) {

    var c = 0;
    var invertedArray = invArray(array);

    for (var i = 0; i < invertedArray.length; i++) {
        c = d[c][p[(i % 8)][invertedArray[i]]];
    }

    return (c === 0);
}

 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#UserForm').formValidation({
                    message: 'This value is not valid',
                    feedbackIcons: {
                        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                    },
                    fields: {aadhaar_no: {
                            validators: {
                                digits: {
                                    message: 'Please use numeric characters only.'
                                },
                                stringLength: {
                                    min: 12,
                                    max: 12,
                                    message: 'The aadhaar number must be 12 characters long'
                                }, identical: {
                                    field: 'c_aadhaar_number',
                                    message: 'The aadhaar number and its confirm field are not the same'
                                }, callback: {
                                    message: 'The input string is not a valid Aadhaar number.',
                                    callback: function (value, validator, $field) {
                                        return validate(value);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
 });
            });

    </script>--%>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="UserForm" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Aadhar Number: "></asp:Label>
&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" MaxLength="12"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
            runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
            ErrorMessage="only numeric values allowed" ForeColor="Red" 
            ValidationExpression="\d+">only numeric values allowed</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        <br />
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


        <asp:Button ID="aadhar_number" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
            onclientclick="generate()" Text="check" />


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then i used a button to call class
Code Behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "none", "<script>executeAfter();</script>", false);
       // ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "validate();", true);

        aadharcard aad = new aadharcard();
        bool isValidnumber = aadharcard.validateVerhoeff(TextBox1.Text);
       // aad.validateVerhoeff("");

        //lblmsg.Text = TextBox1.Text + "valid number";
        if (isValidnumber)
        {
            lblmsg.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblmsg.Text = "valid number";
        }
        else
        {
            lblmsg.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            lblmsg.Text = "Invalid number";
        }

    }
```

Below is my class:
aadharcard.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for aadharcard
/// </summary>
public class aadharcard
{
    static int[,] d = new int[,]
        {
            {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5}, 
            {2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6}, 
            {3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7}, 
            {4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8}, 
            {5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1}, 
            {6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2}, 
            {7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3}, 
            {8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4}, 
            {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0}
        };

    // The permutation table
    static int[,] p = new int[,]
        {
            {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 
            {1, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 3, 0, 9, 4}, 
            {5, 8, 0, 3, 7, 9, 6, 1, 4, 2}, 
            {8, 9, 1, 6, 0, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7}, 
            {9, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 8, 7, 0}, 
            {4, 2, 8, 6, 5, 7, 3, 9, 0, 1}, 
            {2, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0, 6, 4, 1, 5}, 
            {7, 0, 4, 6, 9, 1, 3, 2, 5, 8}
        };

    // The inverse table
    static int[] inv = { 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };


    /// <summary>
    /// Validates that an entered number is Verhoeff compliant.
    /// NB: Make sure the check digit is the last one!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="num"></param>
    /// <returns>True if Verhoeff compliant, otherwise false</returns>
    public static bool validateVerhoeff(string num)
    {
        int c = 0;
        int[] myArray = StringToReversedIntArray(num);

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
        {
            c = d[c, p[(i % 8), myArray[i]]];
        }

        return c==0;

    }

    //public static bool validateAadharNumber(String aadharNumber)
    //{
    //    Pattern aadharPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{12}");
    //    bool isValidAadhar = aadharPattern.matcher(aadharNumber).matches();
    //    if (isValidAadhar)
    //    {
    //        isValidAadhar = aadharcard.validateVerhoeff(aadharNumber);
    //    }
    //    return isValidAadhar;
    //}

    /// <summary>
    /// For a given number generates a Verhoeff digit
    /// Append this check digit to num
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="num"></param>
    /// <returns>Verhoeff check digit as string</returns>
    public static string generateVerhoeff(string num)
    {
        int c = 0;
        int[] myArray = StringToReversedIntArray(num);

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
        {
            c = d[c, p[((i + 1) % 8), myArray[i]]];
        }

        return inv[c].ToString();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a string to a reversed integer array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="num"></param>
    /// <returns>Reversed integer array</returns>
    private static int[] StringToReversedIntArray(string num)
    {
        int[] myArray = new int[num.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
        {
            myArray[i] = int.Parse(num.Substring(i, 1));
        }

        Array.Reverse(myArray);

        return myArray;

    }
}
```

So,Then You just run it and you will get the required result.
cheers..:)

Answer (score 0):

Use this Algorithm to validate the aadhara number. For other languages refer this https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Checksums/Verhoeff_Algorithm

```
    var d=[
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5], 
        [2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6], 
        [3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7], 
        [4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
        [5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1], 
        [6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2], 
        [7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3], 
        [8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4], 
        [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
    ];

    // permutation table p
    var p=[
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
        [1, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 3, 0, 9, 4], 
        [5, 8, 0, 3, 7, 9, 6, 1, 4, 2], 
        [8, 9, 1, 6, 0, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7], 
        [9, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 8, 7, 0], 
        [4, 2, 8, 6, 5, 7, 3, 9, 0, 1], 
        [2, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0, 6, 4, 1, 5], 
        [7, 0, 4, 6, 9, 1, 3, 2, 5, 8]
    ];

    // inverse table inv
    var inv = [0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

    // converts string or number to an array and inverts it
    function invArray(array){

        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(array) == "[object Number]"){
            array = String(array);
        }

        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(array) == "[object String]"){
            array = array.split("").map(Number);
        }

        return array.reverse();

    }

    // generates checksum
    function generate(array){

        var c = 0;
        var invertedArray = invArray(array);

        for (var i = 0; i < invertedArray.length; i++){
            c = d[c][p[((i + 1) % 8)][invertedArray[i]]];
        }

        return inv[c];
    }

    // validates checksum
    function validate(array) {

        var c = 0;
        var invertedArray = invArray(array);

        for (var i = 0; i < invertedArray.length; i++){
            c=d[c][p[(i % 8)][invertedArray[i]]];
        }

        return (c === 0);
    }

var valid = validate(111122223333);
if (valid) {
   //valid
} else {
  //not valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="test" onchange="validateVerhoeff(this);"/>

<script>
var d = [
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
   [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5], 
   [2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6], 
   [3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7], 
   [4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
   [5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1], 
   [6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2], 
   [7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3], 
   [8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4], 
   [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
 ]
 var p = [
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
   [1, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 3, 0, 9, 4], 
   [5, 8, 0, 3, 7, 9, 6, 1, 4, 2], 
   [8, 9, 1, 6, 0, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7], 
   [9, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 8, 7, 0], 
   [4, 2, 8, 6, 5, 7, 3, 9, 0, 1], 
   [2, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0, 6, 4, 1, 5], 
   [7, 0, 4, 6, 9, 1, 3, 2, 5, 8]
 ]
```

function validateVerhoeff(obj)

```
 {
 var aadharNumber=obj.value;
 if(aadharNumber.length!=12)
 {
 alert("Aadhar should be 12 Digit");
 obj.value="";
 obj.focus();
 return false;
 }

 if(isNaN(aadharNumber))
 {
 alert("Aadhaar must be a number");
 obj.value="";     
 obj.focus();
 return false;
 }


   var c = 0;
   var invertedArray = aadharNumber.split('').map(Number).reverse();
    var len = invertedArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) 
   {
           c = d[c][p[(i % 8)][invertedArray[i]]];
   }
   
   
  
   return (c === 0);
 }

</script>
```